# What's the effect of dual-casting soul trap?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have the dual casting perk for conjuration and it does the conjured undead/atronach last longer but what is the effect on the soul trap spell? Does it increases the range or the time you've to kill the enemy before it fades?

Comment: I'd imagine it increases time that you can kill them in, but can't say for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dual-casting Soul Trap makes it last longer, as per the description on the `Conjuration Dual Casting` perk.